# How to join two MySQL results into one?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two result :

```
- | month      | first_time_buyers |
- | 2016-07-01 |                 2 |
- | 2016-08-01 |                 2 |

- | month      | returned_buyers |
- | 2016-08-01 |               1 |
- | 2016-09-01 |               2 |
```

I want to join them into one result like:

```
 - | date       | first_time_buyers | returned_buyers |
 - | 2016-07-01 |                 2 |               0 |
 - | 2016-08-01 |                 2 |               1 |
 - | 2016-09-01 |                 0 |               2 |
```

Comment: How do you expect us to help you? Show your query, your data, your tables.

Comment: Please format your text. :(

Comment: Is that two different table and how do you recognize the buyer (With id)?

Comment: text is formatted,. please help me !!

Comment: How did you create the two initial results? Are they tables or query outputs?

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no FULL JOIN in MySQL, you need to use UNION ALL the two join queries with group by in outer query.

```
SELECT month, 
       first_time_buyers, 
       returned_buyers 
FROM   (SELECT table1.month, 
               Ifnull(first_time_buyers, 0) AS first_time_buyers, 
               Ifnull(returned_buyers, 0)   AS returned_buyers 
        FROM   table1 
               LEFT JOIN table2 
                      ON table1.month = table2.month 
        GROUP  BY month 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT table2.month, 
               Ifnull(first_time_buyers, 0) AS first_time_buyers, 
               Ifnull(returned_buyers, 0)   AS returned_buyers 
        FROM   table2 
               LEFT JOIN table1 
                      ON table2.month = table1.month 
        GROUP  BY month) t 
GROUP  BY month;
```

Comment: can you give me a query , please

Comment: Edited my answer. Have a look at it.